# Need to sequentially show text in 2 edittexts using Java

Tags: java, android

I am making an application where sound clip of a digit is played and i show that digit in an edittext. This is done twice as i need two digits.Even though i've put the functionality in two different functions and called one after the other, the sounds are played first, and the digits are shown after the second digit's sound clip is played(meaning that both the digits are shown at once after the second digit's sound clip).

I want to do this sequentially i.e sound clip of first digit is to be played, that digit should be shown in the first edittext, then the next sound clip is to be played and that digit should shown in the second edittext. I have tried thred.sleep() but it doesnt work for me. Still the same issue..
 The java code is as follows:

```
public class quickmaths extends AppCompatActivity {




    String digit_array[]=new String[] {"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"};
    int digit_sounds[]= new int[] {R.raw.zero,R.raw.one,R.raw.two,R.raw.three,R.raw.four,R.raw.five,R.raw.six,R.raw.seven,R.raw.eight,R.raw.nine,R.raw.ten};

    MediaPlayer random_digit_sound,random_digit_sound2;
    TextView first_num,second_num;
    int random_digit1,random_digit2;
    String random_digit_literal;
    Button btn;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quickmaths);

        first_num=findViewById(R.id.first_num);
        second_num=findViewById(R.id.second_num);


        btn=findViewById(R.id.button2);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                genRandomDigitFirstNum();



                pause(3000);


                genRandomDigitSecondNum();

            }
        });









    }


    int numberGenerator()
    {
        int rand_number=(int)(Math.random()*((10-0)+1) + 0);
        return rand_number;
    }

    int numberGenerator1(int num)
    {
        int rand_number=(int)(Math.random()*((10-0)+1) + 0);
        if(rand_number==num)
        {
            numberGenerator1(rand_number);
        }


        return rand_number;

    }


    void genRandomDigitFirstNum()

    {
        random_digit1=numberGenerator();
        random_digit_sound=MediaPlayer.create(quickmaths.this,digit_sounds[random_digit1]);
        random_digit_sound.start();
        first_num.setText(digit_array[random_digit1]);




    }

    void genRandomDigitSecondNum()

    {

        random_digit2=numberGenerator1(random_digit1);
        random_digit_sound2=MediaPlayer.create(quickmaths.this,digit_sounds[random_digit2]);
        random_digit_sound2.start();
        second_num.setText(digit_array[random_digit2]);


    }

    public static void pause(int ms) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(ms);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.err.format("IOException: %s%n", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain your problem clearly

Comment: For example, A sound clip saying "9" is played. The digit 9 should be shown in the first edittext. Then for the second digit, a sound clip saying "2" is played, and the digit 2 should be shown in the second edittext. This is what i want to happen. Instead, sound of 9 is played. Then sound of 2 is played. And then both the digits are shown in their respective edittexts at once. I want this to happen one by one.

Comment: If you want to play next sound clip if first one completed then add a listener on the media player and then call your second method in that listener

Comment: Solved my problem. Thanks!